# Getting 404 not found in localhost:4200

Tags: angular, api, angular-cli

I'm trying to pass datas from "http://localhost:8082/api/kanchiwork/" to "http://localhost:4200/". My proxy.config.json file is :

```
    {
      "context": [
        "/api/**"
      ],
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      },
      "ws": false,
      "target": "http://localhost:8082",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
  ]
```

and my service file is given below.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeopleService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  fetchPeople(): Observable<Object>{
    return this.http.get('/api/kanchiwork/');
    //return this.http.get('assets/response.json');
  };

}
```

. When I tried to pass the values am getting message as ""GET localhost:4200/api/kanchiwork 404 (Not Found)" in console.

Comment: Whats you api end point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8082",
    "secure": false
  },
  "logLevel": "debug"    
}
```

Either you can run ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

else you can update your package.json scripts property:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

and then run npm start

Note: If you change anything in proxy.conf you need to re-run(ng serve/ npm start) your application to see the changes in action.

Comment: Hey @Amit, should logLevel = debug be allowed  in a production environment?

Comment: @AnshumanKumar No you should not use it in production

Answer (score 2):

Try this in `proxy.conf.json`:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8082/",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  },
  "logLevel": "debug"

}
```

now run the app with this command:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Comment: I think you should explore first.

Comment: you mean there is no routeprefix

Comment: in pathRewrite try giving "/".

Comment: it does work for me
{"ProductDetails":[{"Product_ID":"404","Product_Name":"SAMAI LADDU","Price":"76.19"},{"Product_ID":"405","Product_Name":"AVARAI KUTHIRAIVALI LADDU","Price":"76.19"}]}

Comment: try creating a stackblitz reproducing the error. then I can have a look

Comment: @Venkat. It doesnot load. you need to test the stackblitz

Comment: @Amit, I have created code in stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg6wqe, but still response is not coming

Comment: Why creation of the proxy resolves the problem ?